# Fedora 17 service menus actions menus don't work

Tags: fedora, desktop, kde

I'm using Fedora 17.  Back when I was using Fedora 8, I would go into /home/el/.kde/share/apps/konqueror/servicemenus and make my whatever.desktop file and it would show up in the actions menu.  But now the whatever.desktop file there has no effect on konqueror.

The konquerer service menus are not working.  The konqueror services menu folder is missing.

How do I get the Actions menu to populate with one of the .desktop scripts to work with Fedora 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution, I had to go through 25 websites before I found one that helped me, this one finally did:**

http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Creating_Konqueror_Service_Menus

Fedora 17 has you put your `something.desktop` file in a different place:

Login as root and place your something.desktop file here:

```
/usr/share/kde4/services/
```

**I'll walk you through exactly what I did so you can get it working:**

Login as root and make the following file called engauge.desktop here:

```
/usr/share/kde4/services/engauge.desktop
```

Edit that file and put exactly these lines in there:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=image/*;
Actions=setAsWallpaper

[Desktop Action setAsWallpaper]
Name=Use As Wallpaper
Icon=background
Exec=dcop kdesktop KBackgroundIface setWallpaper %U 6
```

Notice two new lines that are important, the `Type=Service` and the `ServiceTypes` line.  Those are not optional.

Save the file and make sure it has 755 permissions.  Open up konqueror in file mode and right click on a .jpg or other image, go to Actions menu and you will see "Use As Wallpaper" item will appear.